# Convert a formatted date/time string into a DateTime object for comparison?

Tags: c#, datetime, automation

I'm writing an automation date and I want to extract a string, turn it into a DateTime object, and compare it with the current date and time.

The string in question has this format: `7/28/2017 1:17:29 PM`

How can I convert it to a DateTime object to compare with the current time (Basically, my end goal is to verify that it is within a few minutes of the current time)

Answer (score 2):

System.Convert can convert to and from many types.  For example...

```
int intElapsedMinutes = (DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime("7/28/2017 1:17:29 PM")).TotalMinutes
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateTime.Parse()` or `DateTime.TryParse()`

Comment: `DateTime.Parse()` worked, thank you. I knew the Method existed, but I didn't think it'd be smart enough to convert the string without some help

Comment: Sometimes it's not.  If the format is constant, use `ParseExact`, or you have a bug waiting to happen.